# Is the access level of strictfp class same as that of default class?

Tags: java, strictfp

I have below 2 classes in different packages:

```
package chapter1.one;

strictfp class SuperClass
{
    protected void testMe()
    {
        System.out.println("Testing myself!");
    }
}


package chapter1.two;

import chapter1.one.*;

public class SubClass extends SuperClass 
{
    public void testIt()
    {
        this.testMe();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SubClass o = new SubClass();
        o.testMe();
        o.testIt();
    }
}
```

Ofcourse the superclass is accessible **if I make it public**, but when I make it strictfp (just to know what access level it supports), I get below error:

**The type SuperClass is not visible.**

So can I say that **strictfp** has the same access levels as that of **default**?

Here is the screenshot where I read it.
[image]

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `strictfp` has anything to do with access control? Have you reserched the meaning of that modifier at all?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I have edited my post.

Comment: What do you think "Nonaccess" means in the image you posted. It is not an access modifier.

Comment: If you take care to read the screenshot, you should notice that these are *class modifiers*, not *access modifiers*. Be very careful to read each word, especially the word "Nonaccess" in plain sight on that screenshot.

Comment: I also got the thing that, "IF I DONT ASK SUCH QUESTION (HOWEVER SILLY IT MAY BE and AS MUCH I GET DOWN VOTED FOR IT), I WONT **LEARN**. Happy. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strictfp` is NOT an access modifier so if you don't use any along with it then the method's access level is default.

`strictfp` means "strict floating points", it's used to guarantee that method will always work the same regardless of what JVM it's running on.